# node-debug how to disable break on uncaught exception

Tags: node-inspector, node-debugger

I am new to node.js, and specifically I am trying to debug some grunt tasks. And I meet an annoying problem when try to debug it with node-debug.

The case is that it breaks on uncaught exception, and somehow there is some trying to get js/json with different path which results in exceptions before really entering my code.

So what I'd like to know is if there is a way to config by passing parameter or set globally to disable the feature that "break on uncaught exception".

I searched for days and have no good luck, so I am posting here for help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a button in the UI that controls whether uncaught exceptions should pause the application. IIRC the state of this buttton is persisted in local storage, thus it's enough to change it only once.

Look at the bottom left of the webpage for an octagonal-shaped button with a pause symbol inside:

[image: screenshot]

The position of the button depends on the DevTools version served by Node Inspector. Older and future versions may have this button placed elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you Miroslav, you are right, this button is the switch and I just verified it's working. I must clicked it once by accident and not aware of it :)